# Organizing Database Structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, eloquent

```
TABLE presentation {
    id BIGINT
    unique_id BIGINT
    name VARCHAR (128)
    description VARCHAR (256)
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
    created_at TIMESTAMP
}
```

I'm creating an application that allows users to create presentations. Each presentation is built within a layout, each layout contains several positions, each position is occupied by an asset (text, image, video).

I'm trying to figure out the best way to make the connection between my presentation, layout and assets.

Initially, I was thinking of having a table for `presentations`, `layouts`, `positions`, `assets`. I obviously need this schema to be flexible, so I can add several new `layouts` with a different number of positions.

I could just create my `presentation` table like so:

```
TABLE presentation {
    id BIGINT
    unique_id BIGINT
    name VARCHAR (128)
    description VARCHAR (256)
    position1 (BIGINT) - would contain an asset_id
    position2 (BIGINT) - would contain an asset_id
    position3 (BIGINT) - would contain an asset_id
    position4 (BIGINT) - would contain an asset_id
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
    created_at TIMESTAMP
}
```

But this is extremely shortsighted and only allows for 4 total positions within a presentation ... but I'd be on my way to bigger and badder things by now.

Or, I somehow make a connection between `presentations`, `layouts`, `positions` and `assets` that would allow for total flexibility ... and this is what I'm trying to get some help with.

I'm not quite sure if I'm over thinking this, or not... the bottom line is that I'm really not sure how to make the proper connection between these models.

Comment: Did you already setup your models and relations in Eloquent?

Comment: Can you specify the how your models should relate to eachother? As in a presentation can have many layouts, a layout can have many positions etc.

Answer (score 1):

The structure in your example would be suited to a child table something like:

```
TABLE presentation_position {
   presentation_id (BIGINT)
   position (INT)
   asset_id (BIGINT)
}
```

You can join this to presentation by the id column (or unique_id) or just query by presentation_id to get a sequence of asset_id values in position order. Something like:

```
select position, asset_id from presentation_position where presentation_id = 555 order by position
```

EDIT:

I'm getting a better idea of your intention from your other comments. I think you just want a structure to keep the on-page positions of assets. Something like this:

```
TABLE presentation_element {
   presentation_id (BIGINT)
   sequence (INT)
   xpos (INT)
   ypos (INT)
   asset_id (BIGINT)
}
```

You could also add columns for the box height, width, etc. as you need them. The presentation_id and sequence columns should be a unique key. So presetation 101 would have rows like:

```
101   1  100  100  19     //place asset 19 at 100,100
101   2  255  20   102    //place asset 102 at 255,20
```

Comment: I'm envisioning being able to query a presentation, and within that object, be able to loop over or extract each asset in it's proper position.

Comment: Ah, you are using "position" like I used "sequence" in my answer. I'll update it a bit...

Comment: So does you example render `layouts` useless? I'm by no means suggesting that my initial thoughts are the right way to go... I just need to create that relationship so that it's scalable.

Comment: If you meant for layouts to somehow define variable positions like a template, I don't think you need them for the presentation. They could be used as metadata to create new presentations. Hope it helps get the ball rolling.

Comment: So you dont think it's necessary to have a model for the positions (which was the point of the layout)? Instead, just allow the UI/UX to dictate where the positions go?

Comment: I made an edit to the answer. You could choose to have layouts that restrict the presentation, but that's a design issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer In Progress**

**There is still work to do, but more input from the author is required*

Your intended structure is not really clear to me yet, but when you setup your realtions first you will have kind of a sketch before you start thinking about database columns.

If you are using Eloquent it would look something like this:

User

```
class User extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'users';

    public function presentations() {
       return $this->hasMany('Presentation');
   }

}
```

Presentation

```
class Presentation extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'presentations';

    public function user() {
       return $this->belongsTo('User');
   }

}
```

Layout

```
class Layout extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'layouts';

    public function positions() {
       return $this->hasMany('Position');
   }

}
```

Position

```
class Layout extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'positions';

    public function layout() {
       return $this->belongsTo('Layout');
   }

}
```

Asset

```
class Asset extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'assets';

    public function layout() {
       return $this->belongsTo('Layout');
   }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know if what I was originally thinking is the best approach. I am using Eloquent, so thanks for going for that angle. The other issue is that at the moment, my assets are in their own individual tables (images, videos, texts).

Comment: I don't think that has to be a problem. Just drop a comment if you know which way you want to go. I like to do this kind of stuff! :)

Comment: I think I'd like to keep my assets within their own respective tables (texts, images, videos). But I dont think I want to bother with the extra tables and models for `layouts` and `positions` ... it seems very redundant, and I'm not even sure what information would be within the `positions` table. So if somehow it would make sense to connect assets and their positions within a presentation (whether that be with a layout or not), I'm not sure. Thoughts?